# Delete in the app instance of express not working

Tags: node.js, express

```
route.delete("/rest/todo/:todo_id",function(req,res){
    console.log("data >> "+JSON.stringify(req.params));
     ContTodo.remove(req,function(err,data){
      if(err){
        res.end(err);

     }
     res.json(data);
 })
})
```

this route not working

but after removing params it is working fine

```
route.delete("/rest/todo",function(req,res){
    console.log("data >> "+JSON.stringify(req.params));
     ContTodo.remove(req,function(err,data){
      if(err){
        res.end(err);

     }
     res.json(data);
 })
})
```

is working fine. what goes wrong with the routing here
i am stucked here trying from a long time

server.js Content

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var toDo  = require("./route/ToDo");

//######## Configuration

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/users");


app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/view'));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());

//Routing
app.use('/',toDo);

//listen server startup

app.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log('server is listning at'+'8080');
});
```

ToDo.js content

```
      var express = require("express");
var route = express.Router();
var ContTodo = require("../controller/ContTodo");

route.get("/rest/delete:",function(req,res){
    console.log("data >> "+JSON.stringify(req.params));
    ContTodo.remove(req,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            res.end(err);

        }
        res.json(data);
    })
})
route.get("/rest/todo",function(req,res){
      ContTodo.find(function(err,data){
          if(err){
            res.end("Something Wrong !!");
          }
          res.json(data);
      })
});

route.post("/rest/todo",function(req,res){
    ContTodo.create(req,function (err,data) {
      if(err){
        res.end("Something Wrong !!");
      }
      res.json(data)
    })
});

module.exports = route;
```

Please some one explain the difference in a manner so that i can under stand the actual fundamental of the web

Comment: What actually isn't working? Could you specify what the expected and actual behaviour is?

Comment: actually delete route not working not in any case

Comment: We need to know what ContTodo.remove() does

Comment: we are not reaching to console.log("data >> "+JSON.stringify(req.params));

Comment: after adding :todo_id in router. it  is not reachable

Comment: are you sure you are including the id in the url?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/todo?todo_id=572323d661927ae23cd5ccb3

Comment: and doing it using postman using delete method

Comment: you are accessing it the wrong way. Understand the difference between `RequestParam` and `PathVaraible` first. you need to call your service ` 
127.0.0.1:8080/rest/todo/572323d661927ae23cd5ccb3`.

Comment: Awesome deendayal i got it. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are accessing it the wrong way. Understand the difference between `RequestParam` and `PathVaraible` first. you need to call your service `127.0.0.1:8080/rest/todo/572323d661927ae23cd5ccb3`